# multiple bar plots with proportions ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a figure using ggplot and facets; facets based on a categorical variable, and in each plot horizontal barplots of proportions. Hope this makes sense :)

dummy dataset:

```
testdf <- read.csv(text = "ONE,TWO
                       0.01,cat1
                       0.01,cat1
                       0.06,cat1
                       0.06,cat1
                       0.011,cat1
                       0.011,cat1
                       0.011,cat1
                       0.016,cat1
                       0.016,cat1
                       0.01,cat2
                       0.06,cat2
                       0.06,cat2
                       0.06,cat2
                       0.011,cat2
                       0.011,cat2
                       0.011,cat2
                       0.012,cat2
                       0.012,cat2")
```

[image: This is what I'm hoping to get]

Its not working for me, this is what I came up with so far:

```
  ggplot(testdf, aes(x=TWO, y=ONE)) +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.3, height=0.2), aes(factor(TWO)), alpha=0.9)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE, aes(fill=factor(TWO))) + facet_grid(.~TWO)+
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I the figure you attached there were no points so I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with the `geom_jitter`. To achieve what you have in the `what I was hoping to get figure` you can use

```
ggplot(testdf, aes(x=ONE)) +
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, aes(fill=factor(TWO)), show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(~TWO)
```

Resulting in

[image: faceted bar plot]

Comment: Thanks Gordon, would you happen to know how to get the percentage instead of counts as x-axis, so all bars would total into 1?

Comment: add `y=..prop..` to the `geom_bar` aesthetics: `geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, aes(y = ..prop.., fill=factor(TWO)), show.legend = FALSE)`